# CheckBox State Is not maintaining after paging to another page in a RAGGRID

Tags: asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a RADGRID, where 1st column is CheckBox , n rest 4 columns are databoud column..
Initially on paging to next page , my items are not dispaying, Then got to know that i have to bind again the gridview via NEEDDATASOURCE, Then on paging to next page remaining items were binding,

There after again 1 problem arises, if i check any item on 1st page n go to next page the items checked on the first page are not maintaining their state(they were unchecked as i move to other page) 
SO how to maintain the state of this checkBox even when i go to next page?
please suggest some solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel using the below method solves my problem,

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/04/maintaining-state-of-checkboxes-while.html

Still am working towards to solve it with some other techniques or tricks, If found any please share.